# Calling non-const method of a derived class from another derived class having the same base

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting

I have some base class and two classes derived from it. I would like to write a method for the first derived class that modifies the object's internal data by calling the already existing method of the second derived class. I want this in order to avoid making a method containing the same lines of code that I've already written for the second derived class.

Is there a safe way to do such thing?
Currently, the way I do it is this:

```
class Base
{
protected:
    int data;
// some public methods
};

class Derived1: public Base
{
private:
    void ModifyData1() { data = 1; }
// some public methods
friend class Derived2;
};

class Derived2: public Base
{
public:
    void ModifyData2()
    {
        (static_cast<Derived1 *>((Base*)this))->Derived1::ModifyData1();
    }
};
```

So the way I understand it, the pointer `this` is implicitly converted to the base pointer (upcasting) and then the `static_cast` is performed on that one, to downcast to class `Derived1`. This modifies the object's private variable `data`, even though we called a method of another derived class.

The code seems to work, but I don't feel secure here, especially since the version with `dynamic_cast` causes segmentation fault. Thanks for any advice!

**UPDATE:** I'm using GCC in Linux.

Comment: This only appears to work.  Let me explain in animal terms what you have.  The base is mammal and the derived classes are cat and dog.  What you are effectively doing is trying to cast a cat into a dog which will not work.

Comment: Sounds like the method should be in the base class

Comment: This violates aliasing. Whether or not it "works" may be observable, but it isn't *definable* per the language. This invokes *undefined behavior*. If you have a workflow that should be accessible by derivations (not plurality) of some Base, then that behavior belongs in that Base, not hacked up like this.

Comment: It is a bit OT (WhiZTiM already correctly answered your question correctly), but I tried every version of gcc at [godbolt's compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/) and every single one of those gives me a compiler error - same for clang and VC++. You must be doing something different.

Comment: MikeMB sorry I forgot to put the following two things in the code above: (Base*) and namespace identifier Derived1:: . These two let me compile. I've updated the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You invoked undefined Behavior with this code:

```
void ModifyData2()
{
    (static_cast<Derived1 *>(this))->ModifyData1();
}
```

because the `this` pointer is not a `Derived1*` neither is `Derived1` a base of its value type, `Derived2`.

---

> I want this in order to avoid making a method containing the same
>   lines of code that I've already written for the second derived class.

Why don't you take that method to the base class? If you don't want to (perhaps because its not a wholistic property of all derived types) you can use an extra derived class which both `Derived1` and `Derived2` will inherit from.

---

```
class Base
{
protected:
    int data;
    // some public methods
};

class DerivedModifier : Base
{
protected:
    virtual void ModifyData() { data = 1; }
};

class Derived1: public DerivedModifier 
{
private:
     void ModifyData1(){
        DerivedModifier::ModifyData();
    }
};

class Derived2: public DerivedModifier 
{
public:
    void ModifyData2(){
        DerivedModifier::ModifyData();
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Shortly after I posted the question it stroke me that I could just put the method in the base class to solve my problem, even though it's not a fully "wholistic" property. Then I went back here and saw your same advice.

Answer (score 0):

The methods to modify the `data` should be placed in the same class as `data`. The parent class hold `data`, it should hold `modifyData()` too.

```
class Base {
public:
    void modifYData() { data = 1}
    // some other public methods
private:
    int data;
};
```

And you'll be able to do the following:

```
Base b;
Derived1 d1;
Derived2 d2;

b.modifyData();
d1.modifyData();
d2.modifyData();
```

If you want the derived classes to behave differently when `modifyDtata()` is called on them, make the method virtual and override it in them.

N.B: Read about [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)"Wikipedia") and [access specifiers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access).